# S3 bucket with SSL with static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket and configured a static website hosting

I want to use SSL so instead of using

http://my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

I have to use
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/

the problem with this is that the **static website hosting** endpoint is still http://my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

I created a redirection rule on it (basically if the requested file returns 404 then I call an API) but is not working because (I assume) the endpoint is the bad one and when I try to access a file that doesn´t exist instead of getting the redirection configured in the static website I get Access Denied. how to deal with this?

notes: I tried to use s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/file.jpg but I get redirected to an amazon page.

Comment: this question would probably be better suited for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: didn´t know about it. I´m web dev so.. new stuff for me but thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by [serving your content through cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html) and then [configuring your cloudfront distribution to use https](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html)

Answer (score 0):

I worked at getting SSL working for a static web site on AWS using a custom domain for two days and, having Googled much and stopped by this posting, finally found this excellent and concise tutorial **Example Walkthroughs - Hosting Websites on Amazon S3** on **AWS** at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/hosting-websites-on-s3-examples.html.  While it seems obvious now, the thing that got the SSL working for me was the final step of **Update the Record Sets for Your Domain and Subdomain**  The guide is very to the point, well written and easy to follow so thought this would help others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Cloudfront (or other Amazon services except for S3) you can use this tool: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/amazon_static_site which allows you to publish a site and use Cloudflare. You will get https too.

To simplify life you can use a generator and then just edit config and deploy files to S3/Cloudflare.